# Using symfony forms, how would you create a category if text input entered

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Trying to create a form in symfony, where I would be linking a Category to a Post.

This is working perfectly, when using existing categories, and the dropdown.

However, I would like there to be a text field next to the dropdown, that when is not empty, creates a category and links it to the post.

I'm currently considering just adding the text field manually (in the twig), and reading the value from the request.

Is there a more elegant way to do this using forms ?

Answer (score 0):

(I can't just comment post. What are your entities ? what symfony version ? show us what you have ever tried)

after submit data :

- check if text field is empty
- if not, check if category name exist
- if not, persist and flush new category
- then $yourObject->setCategory($newCategory)
- persist and flush yourObject

Answer (score 0):

You could create a collection. And use the allow_add property